# Convert DateTime string using Javascript and Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script, calendar

I have a time format I get from Google Calendar events, and i need to convert it to be readable in Google Timeline Charts (using Google Apps Scripts). I would've thought it would use the same format but it doesn't.

---

I need this: ***"Tue Oct 01 11:30:00 GMT+10:00 2019"***

To resemble this: ***"new Date(2019, 10, 01, 11, 30)"***

---

Here is what I have so far, but the problem is Apps Script **can't find 'DateTime'** (*"ReferenceError: "DateTime" is not defined."*)

Any thoughts on how to load DateTime or another method to convert?

---

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Tue Oct 01 11:30:00 GMT+10:00 2019", 
    "ddd mmm dd hh:mm:00 \\\\\\\\\ yyyy+", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy+, mm, dd, hh, mm, ss");

Logger.log(result);
```

Comment: In ECMAScript, months are zero indexed so for October you want `new Date(2019, 9, 01, 11, 30)`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Google Apps Script, to format a date as a string use [Utilities.formatDate(...)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

`DateTime.ParseExact(...)` isn't standard JavaScript. You could declare it before using it, or just use the above suggestion.